# Error: (The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and getting an Error in passing the String and looked everywhere and finally adding this in StackOverflow

the error is

`Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.`

```
void errorSnackBar(BuildContext context, String? text) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
    duration: new Duration(seconds: 4),
    content: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          Icons.error,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: new Text(text),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#using-nullable-types

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem

In my case, I had to use null safety.

```
final String? name
```

I had to use a **!** mark to make it work. Such like: if I wanted to call it

```
index.name!
```

Answer (score 4):

This may help someone new,
I had similar issues, the way I resolve it

```
 Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
      child: new Text(text ?? 'Default Value'),
    ),
```

refer to this [Link](https://flutteragency.com/solve-a-non-null-string-must-be-provided-to-a-text-widget/) for more information

Answer (score 3):

`Text()` requires a `String` as its first parameter (i.e. not `null`). `null` is not a valid value for the type `String`, just like `123` is not a valid value for the type `String`.

If your error message is a `String?`, you need to handle the case where it is `null` before you can pass it to `Text()`. Some options are:

1. Check if it is null and return early:

```dart
void errorSnackBar(BuildContext context, String? text) {
  if (text == null) return;
  // dart uses "type promotion" to know that text is definitely not null here
  final textWidget = Text(text);  // this is fine
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) ... // show snackbar
}
```

2. If you know that you only call `errorSnackBar` when `text` is non-null, try changing it's type:

```dart
void errorSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
  // rest of the method the same
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your reply.if (text == null) return; final textWidget = Text(text); worked for me I was not able to guess that String? text stores null in Text

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue when I was new in Flutter.
The best thing to do is using some default value instead of null, so that if you'll get null instead of some text you can use some value. i.e.

```
Text? text;
text = somethingComingFromResponseOrServer();
errorSnackBar(context,text);
```

Now let's assume you've passed this text to snackbar and the value was null we can use here dart's null check operator `Datatype? variableName;`
now if the vaiable has nothing or some text use `??` to check. and then giving some default value. like `variableName ?? 'Hello variable is null so this will be the default value'`

```
void errorSnackBar(BuildContext context, String? text) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
    duration: new Duration(seconds: 4),
    content: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          Icons.error,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Text(text ?? 'Some Default text to show if text is null'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make text to String using .toString()

```
 void errorSnackBar(BuildContext context, String? text) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
        duration: new Duration(seconds: 4),
        content: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.error,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
              child: new Text(text.toString()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

better option which I like is:

```
void errorSnackBar(BuildContext context, String? text)
 {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
    duration: new Duration(seconds: 4),
    content: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          Icons.error,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: new Text('$text'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: String? means, that the string could be null. If you use '$text' I expect, that the text value will be "null", that is not helpful for the user in most cases. I suggest to use the "??" (you can say "or else") to make in explicit. So even if you would like to show "null" in your UI, text ?? "null" shows that it's intentionally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).