# (The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String') What is the difference between String and String in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, type-conversion, dart-null-safety

lately i always get errors like:

(The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String')
or (The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File') and i don't know the difference between em or what to do.
help me please

this error made my life much harder this days please help guys

Comment: if you show your code I can help you resolve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: (The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.) in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893455/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-str) Also you can check https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#using-nullable-types

Answer (score 0):

Since dart introduced sound null-safety a **String** variable can not be null,
but if your variable might be null you can declare it as **String?**.
Therefor you can not assign something that might be null(String?) to something null-safe(String).
Same with File? and File.

with ? at the end of a type you indicate that it might be null.

https://dart.dev/null-safety